# Can't run pywin32 post install

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to use winpexpect on windows 7 64 bit on an AMD processor. For this, I installed pywin32, the executable called `pywin32-214.win-amd64-py2.7`. The graphical installer seemed to run successfully, but I get this error when I try to import `winpexpect`:

```
>>> import winpexpect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alexei\wordseer_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\winpexpect.py", li
ne 11, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\Alexei\wordseer_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\pywin32-214-py2.7-
win32.egg\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\Alexei\wordseer_flask\venv\lib\site-packages\pywin32-214-py2.7-
win32.egg\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

When I try to run `C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 601, in <module>
    install()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 311, in install
    LoadSystemModule(lib_dir, "pywintypes")
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 149, in LoadSystemModu
le
    ('.dll', 'rb', imp.C_EXTENSION))
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: "Did you install 64 bit python? with the 64 bit pywin32? Or 32 bit python with 32 pywin32? Or neither? If one is 32 bit the other should be too."  - [Joren485](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1474685/joren485) (too low rep to comment)

Answer (score 1):

When I installed pyinstaller, I also got the same error:
`import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`
Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package fixed the error.